# How to use a for loop inside a try catch block

Tags: java, try-catch

Hello I am trying to use Jsoup to create an ArrayList of images pulled from all jpgs on a site. I am encountering nullPointerException as if the for loop is not there.

```
try {
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("www.enterwebsitehere.com").get();
    jpgs = doc.select("img[src$=.jpg]");

    for (int countPics = 0; countPics > 10; countPics++) {
        Element currentPic = jpgs.get(countPics);

        String currentPicString = currentPic.toString();
        int startofAddress = currentPicString.indexOf("http:");
        int endofAddress = (currentPicString.indexOf(".jpg") + 4);
        String urlOfImage = currentPicString.substring(startofAddress, endofAddress);

        URL url = new URL(urlOfImage);
        Image currentImage = ImageIO.read(url);
        imageList.add(currentImage);
    }


} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I believe I need to bring some variables outside of the catch block?

Thankyou for any help you can offer.

EHarpham

Comment: Please post the stack trace of the exception.

Comment: @EHarpham, you should try to isolate the problem. Your problem here has nothing to do with the try / catch block. It is in the loop itself. Your loop is just skipping because the condition is evaluating false, as they already said at the answers. I'm writing this because you are a new user here and I'm just trying to help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CountPics >10 is evaluating to false.  (0 > 10) is false.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant : `for (int countPics = 0; countPics < 10; countPics++)`

Note the reversal of `countPics > 10` to `countPics < 10`